# How to query database where date and time field are separate?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In Table, Time and date fields are two separate fields. I need to make a query something like this give all records where date and time <= givenDateTime. How do i do that please?

EDIT
My query:-

```
select DateField, TimeField from Table1 where DateField <= '07/26/2009' and TimeField <= '16:26:20'
```

Result is:-

2008-04-22 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 23:59:58.000

2009-04-15 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 23:59:56.000

2006-06-06 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 23:59:53.000

See the Time above in results. Its wrong

Comment: Are the fields stored as plain text or in real date columns?  If so, what date is the time field stored with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break up the `@givenDateTime` to the date component and the time component and use `AND` to build up the `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @givenDate DATETIME 
SELECT @givenDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @givenDateTime))

DECLARE @givenTime DATETIME 
SELECT @givenTime =  CONVERT(varchar(2),
      CASE
           WHEN DATEPART([hour], @givenDateTime) > 12 THEN CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEPART([hour], @givenDateTime) - 12))
           WHEN DATEPART([hour], @givenDateTime) = 0 THEN '12'
           ELSE CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART([hour], @givenDateTime))
      END
 ) + ':' +
 CONVERT(char(2), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(5), @givenDateTime, 108), 4, 2)) + ' ' +
 CONVERT(varchar(2),
      CASE
           WHEN DATEPART([hour], @givenDateTime) > 12 THEN 'PM'
           ELSE 'AM'
      END
 ) 

SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE tableDate <= @givenDate AND tableTime <= @givenTime
```

Date conversion taken from [here](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2006/02/17/1458.aspx).
Time conversion taken from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/eporter/archive/2004/04/28/122343.aspx).

Note that the `@givenTime` will have a date of `01 Jan 1900` (plus the time), so be sure that your where clause takes that into account.

Comment: I did that already but results are not accurate. see my edited question above

Comment: Working now. Only thing is that I have to pass Date with the time in time field. something like this:- select DateField, TimeField from Table1 where DateField <= '07/26/2009' and TimeField <= '1899-12-30 16:26:20'

Answer (score 1):

With your data model:

```
select  DateField, 
        TimeField 
from    Table1 
where   (DateField < '07/26/2009')
    or  (DateField = '07/26/2009' and TimeField <= '16:26:20')
```

But ideally you can have a `computed` column that would have complete date and time `DateTimeField`, and just query relative to this one. If this is the query you do often, then you could make this computed column persisted and even create indexes on this column. Creating this computed column in SQL Server 2008 is trivial if you use `DATE` and `TIME` data types (as shown in Cade's answer):

```
DateTimeField AS CONVERT(DATETIME, DateField + TimeField) PERSISTED NOT NULL
```

In case of SQL Server 2005 you might need to do some conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add datetime values naively.

http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/2558

Note that this may not be SARG'able.

I'm assuming here that one column is SQL Server 2008 DATE and one is TIME.

```
-- Datetime Combination Example 
SELECT CAST(dt AS datetime) + CAST(tm AS datetime) AS dtm
FROM (
    SELECT CAST('6/7/2010' AS DATE) AS dt, CAST('12:34:00' AS TIME) AS tm
) AS X
```

If they are already both datetime:

```
SELECT dt + tm AS dtm
FROM (
    SELECT CAST('6/7/2010' AS DATETIME) AS dt, CAST('12:34:00' AS DATETIME) AS tm
) AS X
```